# Writing an enriched graph as a colimit

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory, homological-algebra, limits-colimits, enriched-category-theory

I am working with enriched directed graphs (aka, directed graphs/quivers such that the edges are objects in a category V). I can write every graph as a filtered colimit of finite graphs, and I can write every edge as a filtered colimit of a certain kind of objects in V.

Is there a way to combine the two in order to write every graph as a filtered colimit of finite graphs whose edges are those objects in V? My intuition says yes, but I can't see how to formalise that.

(I tried to phrase this in a more general way, but the category V is cochain complexes over a ring and the "certain objects" are perfect complexes, if that helps.)

Edit: "Enriched directed graphs" are given by a set of objects $Obj(X)$ and a collection of edges $X(x,y)_{x,y\in Obj(X)}$ that are all objects in $V$.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your definition. Could you be more formal? What do you mean by enriched directed graphs? You write that edges are objects in $V$ what about vertices?

Comment: I edited the post to give a more exact definition of enriched directed graphs. Is this better? It's my first time using MathStackExchange and I'm pretty lost...